# Which Design Pattern am I looking for?

Tags: php, design-patterns, factory-pattern

I am a little bit confused by chosing the right design pattern for my problem. Here is my code:

```
<?php

class Report_Journal ...
class Report_Recommendation ...
class Report_Customer ...

$type = "journal"; // value can also be "recommendation or customer"

?>
```

Now I want to create the correct object for that specific type, means in that case Report_Journal. I was thinking of the factory pattern, but what I do not like about a factory are its dependencies that are not injected but defined inside the class. How would you solve the problem? Thanks in advance.

BR,
Chris

Comment: What should be the _defined_ part? It all seems parametric, and with some reflection you don't need any hard coded class name

Comment: How would you decide which class to chose regarding e.g a user input? Let's say I have a select box where a user can select three different types of report and the user's choice should be handled by a given class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The factory pattern is from my point of view the correct approach. You should create an `interface` in the first place to define the common interface of all those types and use that to put in your parameter list of all those methods using that classes.

```
function blub(myInterface $obj)
```

that is explicitly needed for depency injection, imagine the `blub` method is used to inject the needed class. Since all your three objects inherit from `myInterface` the method `blub` applies for all of them.

Finally you can create a factory method like

```
function getInstance($objectType, $params){
    if (!class_exists($objectType)) {
        throw new Exception('Bad type');
    }
    $instance = new $objectType($params);
    return $instance;
}
```

for a deeper look (based on php) you can have a look into that blog post

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/understanding-and-applying-polymorphism-in-php/

Comment: Hi Matthias, thank you for your answer. But what I do not like about a factory is that I create an object directly inside another object. Regarding dependency injection the factory pattern seems to break some rules here or am I wrong?

Comment: that is why you should create an interface, so you can still use depency injection. That way you can provide via a Setter all kind of classes since all of three of them will inherit from your interface

Answer (score 0):

You could use a variable as the class name, which PHP allows since it is an interpreted language:

```
<?php
$class_name = "Report_" . ucfirst($type);
$object = new $class_name();
?>
```

Comment: Hey Tristan, thanks for your answer. Maybe my question is not clear enough but the important thing for me is to determine which object to create by a given parameter. But thanks a lot.

Comment: You can freely put this code in a function and let $type be a parameter of it. In this case, you can refer to @MatthiasLaug 's answer which shows this in a more detailed example.